# Android. Help on run time layout Design.

Tags: android, android-layout

How do we set edittext toRightof textView during run time layout Design on Android?

We want to make a layout design during run time like

```
TextView1      EditText1

TextView2      EditText2


     SubmitButon
```

Answer (score 3):

put this code in Your `onCreate()`

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
sv.addView(ll);

TextView tv = new TextView(this);

tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");

ll.addView(tv);

EditText et = new EditText(this);

et.setText("weeeeeeeeeee~!");

ll.addView(et);


this.setContentView(sv);
```

Answer (score 1):

First Create a TableLayout and put TextView1, EditText1, TextView2 & EditText2 in it. After TableLayout use normal Relative Layout to add Submit Button & make sure to change the Button's Gravity to Center Horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Personally, I would nest some layouts like so (Note- not real code, just to get the point across):

```
<LinearLayout orientation:vertical >
   <LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
      <TextView layout_width="0" layout_weight="1" />
      <EditText layout_width="0" layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout orientation:horizontal>
      <TextView layout_width="0" layout_weight="1" />
      <EditText layout_width="0" layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout>
      <Button layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Set all of the LinearLayouts to fill the screen width-wise and wrap content or set your own spacing vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in layout-xml file:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <EditText layout_width="0" layout_weight="1" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" >
      <EditText android:layout_width="200" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <EditText android:layout_width="200" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
      <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```